# Kotlin Coroutine Flow: When does wasting resource happen when using Flow

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I am reading this [article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/a-safer-way-to-collect-flows-from-android-uis-23080b1f8bda) to fully understand the dos and donts of using Flow while comparing it to my implementation, but I can't grasp clearly how to tell if you are wasting resource when using Flow or flow builder. When is the time a flow is being release/freed in memory and when is the time that you are wasting resource like accidentally creating multiple instances of flow and not releasing them?

I have a UseCase class that invokes a repository function that returns Flow. In my ViewModel this is how it looks like.

```
class AssetViewModel constructor(private val getAssetsUseCase: GetAssetsUseCase) : BaseViewModel() {

    private var job: Job? = null

    private val _assetState = defaultMutableSharedFlow<AssetState>()

    fun getAssetState() = _assetState.asSharedFlow()

    init {
        job = viewModelScope.launch {
            while(true) {
                if (lifecycleState == LifeCycleState.ON_START || lifecycleState == LifeCycleState.ON_RESUME)
                    fetchAssets()
                delay(10_000)
            }
        }
    }

    fun fetchAssets() {

        viewModelScope.launch {

            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                getAssetsUseCase(
                    AppConfigs.ASSET_BASE_URL,
                    AppConfigs.ASSET_PARAMS,
                    AppConfigs.ASSET_SIZES[AppConfigs.ASSET_LIMIT_INDEX]
                ).onEach {

                    when(it){

                        is RequestStatus.Loading -> {
                            _assetState.tryEmit(AssetState.FetchLoading)
                        }

                        is RequestStatus.Success -> {
                            _assetState.tryEmit(AssetState.FetchSuccess(it.data.assetDataDomain))
                        }

                        is RequestStatus.Failed -> {
                            _assetState.tryEmit(AssetState.FetchFailed(it.message))
                        }

                    }

                }.collect()
            }

        }

    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        job?.cancel()
        super.onCleared()
    }

}
```

The idea here is we are fetching data from remote every 10 seconds while also allowing on demand fetch of data via UI.

Just a typical useless UseCase class

```
class GetAssetsUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: AssetsRepository // Passing interface not implementation for fake test
) {

    operator fun invoke(baseUrl: String, query: String, limit: String): Flow<RequestStatus<AssetDomain>> {
        return repository.fetchAssets(baseUrl, query, limit)
    }

}
```

The concrete implementation of repository

```
class AssetsRepositoryImpl constructor(
    private val service: CryptoService,
    private val mapper: AssetDtoMapper
) : AssetsRepository {

    override fun fetchAssets(
        baseUrl: String,
        query: String,
        limit: String
    ) = flow {

        try {
            emit(RequestStatus.Loading())
            val domainModel = mapper.mapToDomainModel(
                service.getAssetItems(
                    baseUrl,
                    query,
                    limit
                )
            )
            emit(RequestStatus.Success(domainModel))
        } catch (e: HttpException) {
            emit(RequestStatus.Failed(e))
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            emit(RequestStatus.Failed(e))
        }

    }

}
```

After reading this [article](https://manuelvivo.dev/sharein-statein) which says that using `stateIn` or `sharedIn` will improve the performance when using a flow, it seems that I am creating new instances of the same flow on-demand. But there is a limitation as the stated approach only works for variable and not function that returns Flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stateIn` and `shareIn` can save resources if there are multiple observers, by avoiding redundant fetching. And in your case, you could set it up to automatically pause the automatic re-fetching when there are no observers. If, on the UI side you use `repeatOnLifecycle`, then it will automatically drop your observers when the view is off screen and then you will avoid wasted fetches the user will never see.

I think it’s not often described this way, but often the multiple observers are just observers coming from the same Activity or Fragment class after screen rotations or rapidly switching between fragments. If you use WhileSubscribed with a timeout to account for this, you can avoid having to restart your flow if it’s needed again quickly.

Currently you emit to from an external coroutine instead of using `shareIn`, so there’s no opportunity to pause execution.

I haven't tried to create something that supports both automatic and manual refetching. Here's a possible strategy, but I haven't tested it.

```
private val refreshRequest = Channel<Unit>(Channel.CONFLATED)

fun fetchAssets() {
    refreshRequest.trySend(Unit)
}

val assetState = flow {
    while(true) {
        getAssetsUseCase(
            AppConfigs.ASSET_BASE_URL,
            AppConfigs.ASSET_PARAMS,
            AppConfigs.ASSET_SIZES[AppConfigs.ASSET_LIMIT_INDEX]
        ).map {
            when(it){
                is RequestStatus.Loading -> AssetState.FetchLoading
                is RequestStatus.Success -> AssetState.FetchSuccess(it.data.assetDataDomain)
                is RequestStatus.Failed -> AssetState.FetchFailed(it.message)
            }
        }.emitAll()
        withTimeoutOrNull(100L) {
             // drop any immediate or pending manual request
             refreshRequest.receive()
        }
        // Wait until a fetch is manually requested or ten seconds pass:
        withTimeoutOrNull(10000L - 100L) {
             refreshRequest.receive()
        }
    }
}.shareIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(4000L), replay = 1)
```

Comment: Yes I used `repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)`. Is this supposed to use inside a ViewModel?

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re asking. `repeatOnLifecycle` is used in the activity or fragment.

Comment: My code above is to replace your current code in your ViewModel class.

Comment: Having issue with `.emitAll()`

Comment: Try replacing `.emitAll()` with `.let { emitAll(it) }`

Comment: It works like a charm! Thanks, just a follow up question should I still need configure this SharedFlows `onBufferOverflow` to `BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST` or not since we call `emitAll` instead of `tryEmit`

Comment: It shouldn't matter in this case. If you leave it, then if the observer falls behind, this flow will suspend and wait before emitting further values. I can't imagine your observer will fall behind since it should be promptly doing stuff with the UI while this source flow is doing IO.

Comment: You are correct as well on `repeatOnLifecycle` as setting it to `RESUMED` save me from handling auto fetches on off screen scenario. Could you explain more what is happening on these lines `withTimeoutOrNull(100L)` `withTimeoutOrNull(10000L - 100L)`? I am guessing that we are checking if there is any request in the channel by calling `.receive()` which then comes from `.trySend(Unit) on every first 100 ms and later 10000 ms. Please enlighten me.

Comment: `refreshRequest` is a conflated channel so it can hold at most one item. It is basically sending a signal to the flow coroutine that it can continue past the `receive` line to repeat the while loop. Wrapping it in `withTimeout` (the second time) is so if we don’t get a manual refresh within 10 seconds, we stop waiting and repeat the loop anyway. And I added the first `withTimeout` with a very short time so we can consume any manual request that might have been made during the previous fetch. Otherwise if the user taps refresh while it’s loading, it would refresh immediately after finishing.

Comment: What is the other significant improvement of this approach compared to my sample if we remove the automatic fetching part leaving on demand request function only?

Comment: There wouldn’t be a performance advantage since there wouldn’t be something automatically happening that you would want to pause when there are no observers. Unless on your UI side it requests manual updates while nothing is observing for changes, which would be silly. But your code could be much more condensed using `map` and `shareIn`.

Comment: Why we no longer specify the Dispatchers here? Can I still explicitly specify it just to make sure I am executing it in IO?

Comment: There is no reason to specify the dispatcher if you aren’t calling a blocking function (or accessing something that’s restricted to a specific single thread, which is rare with coroutines). It’s a code smell if you do it because then it will make people think you are calling a blocking function there. If you’re doing it “just in case”, that’s cargo cult programming and a sign of bigger problems to anyone reviewing your code.

Comment: Isn't getting response from API using Retrofit a blocking function? Here we have uscase that calls a concrete implementation of repository that will execute a Retrofit service. I wonder if marking a Retrofit service function `suspend` all do those stuff already?

Comment: Yes, it certainly does. It is a design error for any suspend function to ever block. Retrofit is robustly designed by people who know what they’re doing. If you define a Retrofit interface with a suspend function, the generated implementation doesn’t block. That’s the whole point of marking it suspend.

Answer (score 0):

To this I would recommend not using flow as the return type of the usecase function and the api call must not be wrapped inside a flow builder.

**Why:**

The api call actually is happening once and then again after an interval it is triggered by the view model itself, returning flow from the api caller function will be a bad usage of powerful tool that is actually meant to be called once and then it must be self-reliant, it should emit or pump in the data till the moment it has a subscriber/collector.

One usecase you can consider when using flow as return type from the room db query call, it is called only once and then the room emits data into it till the time it has subscriber.

.....

```
fun fetchAssets() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
//          loading true
            val result=getusecase(.....)
            when(result){..process result and emit on state..}
//            loading false
        }
}
```

.....

```
suspend operator fun invoke(....):RequestStatus<AssetDomain>{
    repository.fetchAssets(baseUrl, query, limit)
}
```

.....

override fun fetchAssets(
baseUrl: String,
query: String,
limit: String
):RequestStatus {

```
    try {
        //RequestStatus.Loading()//this can be managed in viewmodel itself
        val domainModel = mapper.mapToDomainModel(
            service.getAssetItems(
                baseUrl,
                query,
                limit
            )
        )
        RequestStatus.Success(domainModel)
    } catch (e: HttpException) {
        RequestStatus.Failed(e)
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        RequestStatus.Failed(e)
    }

}
```

Comment: The official Flows documentation has many examples of finite flows. They aren’t an anti-pattern. It seems like the only reason you’re giving for not using them this way is that Flows are powerful, which isn’t really a reason…? If you weren’t supposed to do this there wouldn’t be standard library functions like FlowCollector.emitAll().

Comment: I must say they are example and here we try to solve some real world problem that have great impact on the behaviour of the app and how the implementation uses the underlying resource.

Comment: Returning a finite Flow of states instead of a single item in a suspend function is not going to change performance of the app. It just changes which layer you catch exceptions in.

Comment: I believe I have given the answer that suits the use case of the given question.